# WPF Textblock / Set BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE tags direct via Inlines.Add()

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

It is here any solution for direct pasting TextBlock Inlines with HTML markup in C# code like this:

```
string example = "Here is <Bold>bold</Bold> text, and here is <Italic>italic</Italic>.";
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(example);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33196/WPF-Html-supported-TextBlock) project